# GitLab: How can I make every commit to a branch with a Jira tag in the branch name create a new Jira comment?

Tags: gitlab, jira

I have gotten GitLab to integrate with Jira so that every commit has a Jira issue name in the commit notes. The comments are updated as seen in this photo:
[image: jira task]

In this case, my commit said "Update README.md GTP-1". Instead of putting the JIRA task GTP-1 in the commit notes, I want to name a branch "GTP-1 add feature" and every time I commit to that branch Jira should update with a note in the same way.

Is there a way to configure this?